# How to use in Angular 8+ set of images stored as SVG?

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

How Electrical symbols library in SVG (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Electrical_symbols_library.svg) might be used in Angular 8+ application ? I would like to have ability to refer electrical elements in order to constract electrical schema on the fly based on provided data in JSON. Is it possible to split Electrical symbols library in SVG (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Electrical_symbols_library.svg) to set of SVG files ? Do we have something similar stored as set of SVG files which are already exists ?

Comment: aren't there libraries like this already? https://github.com/nturley/netlistsvg

Comment: Looks interesting. Also found Linear Electronic Circuits SVG Vectors https://www.svgrepo.com/vectors/linear-electronic-circuits/ which might be used during electrical schema construction. It would be good to find more comprehensive SVG library.